# lightbox causes the page to jump to the end

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I am using the Slider PRO plugin on wordpress.

```
[slider_pro_lightbox] <h3 style="text-align: center;">Letters From Parents</h3> 
  <a class="slider-pro-lightbox-26">
  <img class="size-medium wp-image-7529 pointer aligncenter" src="http://xxx/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/dreamstime_xs_15537749-300x200.jpg" alt="dreamstime_xs_15537749" width="300" height="200" />
</a>
```

When I click on the image a lighbox pops up with content, as it should. However the page also jumps to the end of the page. 
I don't think this is a plugin issue as it isn't happening on another site where I am doing the same thing. 
You can see the issue [here](http://meor.org/homepage-features/for-parents) by clicking on the image under'Letters to Parents' 
I checked the console and I can't see any error causing this. 
What is causing the page to jump to the end? 
Thanks

Comment: The site it is working on is http://grmanaginggreatness.com/temp/meor/homepage-features/for-parents. There is no difference in the code. Why is it working on one site and not the other?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on the page. The console shows "TypeError: c.curCSS is not a function" in jquery.ui.core.min.js

The "curCSS" function was removed in jquery 1.8. You are loading both jquery 1.6 and 1.11.

You could remove jquery 1.11 or remove version 1.6 and update jquery.ui to the newest version (at least 1.8.22 - See [this ticket](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8501)).

Comment: I have the same jquery on my test site where I am running the code and it works fine. I'm not sure this could be the issue.

Comment: I updated to jQuery to 2.1.3 and it is still not working. Any idea why?

Comment: I think you need to update jQuery.ui, because it is trying to use a function that no longer exists in jQuery

Comment: Can you see where version 1.6, I can't find it to remove it.

Comment: It seems to be included by the theme. I think it is either hardcoded in the HTML or they added it directly to wp_head.

Comment: I removed it and it didn't fix the issue. (so I put it back in.)

Comment: You need to update jQuery.UI. You are still using version 1.8.16 but you need 1.8.22